# How do I access variable from a function and use it in my widget - Flutter storage variable

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this project, so I already stored the data I need in flutter storage but I'm unable to pick that data and use it in my text widget

```
  checkname() async {
  String? name = await storage.read(key: "name");

  setState(() {
     splitname = name;
  });
  print(splitname);
}

checkname();
```

I created this function to read the value in the storage but but it kept on printing the value about a 1000 times a minutes and I feel something might go wrong, is there a way I could go around it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Printing the value about a 1000 times indicates that you are calling the function **inside** `build` method.

Here's on overall of what you should do:

- create a `statuful` widget
- call `checkname` inside `initState` function of the widget

Comment: That's a nice one but it will print each time I go back to that page, it's I just want it to do once but this okay

Comment: if you want to call it once for the whole running of the app, use it at top widgets of your widget tree